# How can I make the drop-down arrow in a Web Part menu bar always display in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm converting a Sharepoint 2007 installation to Sharepoint 2010. In 2010 each Web Part has an arrow in right side of the menu bar that only displays on mouse hover. How can I make that arrow always display? I've tried adding this to my custom CSS:

```
.ms-WPHeaderMenuImg{
    visibility:visible !important;
}
```

The visibility set by corev4.css is hidden, but when I change it to visible in my CSS I still only see the image on mouse hover. Is there some JavaScript that is controlling this action? If so, where is it and can I override it? If not, how is this arrow showing and hiding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your priority of CSS imports and make sure your custom CSS is actually being applied because the code you have is correct.  I was able to verify that on a standard page, adding a webpart did not show the drop-down arrow.  When I then added in your code (and actually I didn't need the !important) then the arrows were shown by default.  There was no JavaScript getting in the way, it was all controlled by CSS.  So the problem may be somewhere else in your code.

One thing to be aware of is that there are two ways to display webparts: with the checkbox to the right of the arrow and without.  That means that the arrows will not line up vertically on the page if you have them visible by default.  This may be why Microsoft chose to hide them (although it also looks cleaner in the 2010 way).

Comment: You're right, I was able to create an un-branded page and apply the style and see the image. I'll continue looking into my code for the issue. Thanks!